# Short status output

Tags: apache2

Is there any way in Ubuntu 18.04.2 to show 'short' status output when checking a service?

In Ubuntu 14.04.5 status output is like this:

[image: short output]

Where in Ubuntu 18.04.2 the same command gives output like this:

[image: very long output]

How can I narrow this output down again to 1 line like in 14.04.5?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I would just like to point out that you should use text [code blocks](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code) instead of images of code and terminal outputs when possible. Basically just copy/paste your text and encapsulate them in tripe backticks ```

Comment: @Dan. Even easier than triple backticks, use the code button in the editor.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It won't give the *same* output, but you can use

```
systemctl is-active apache2
```

See `man systemctl` for details.